# Inner product between gradients of two functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

It is well known that the orthogonality of two functions can be measured by their inner product. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_functions In discrete case, the inner product is basically $\sum_i f(x_i)g(x_i)$

But have people studied the inner product between their 1st order derivatives? In particular, in the discrete case, it would be $\sum_i \left<\nabla f(x_i), \nabla g(x_i)\right>$, where $\left<\vec a, \vec b\right>$ denotes the inner product between vector $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. Does it measure anything of intuitive sense?

Comment: The name Sobolev comes to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space